React Native - Component State Changes
I have a basic React Native component. The component looks like this:
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Clipboard, Pressable, StyleSheet, Text, TextInput, View } from 'react-native';

interface CopyInputBoxProps {
    value: string;
}

interface CopyInputBoxState {
    textValue: string;
}

export class CopyInputBox extends Component<CopyInputBoxProps, CopyInputBoxState> {
    constructor(props: CopyInputBoxProps) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            textValue: props.value
        };
    }

    onCopyPress = () => {
      Clipboard.setString(this.state.textValue)
    };

    onInputChange = (text: string) => {
        this.setState({ textValue: text });
    }

  render() { 
    const { textValue } = this.state;

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <TextInput style={styles.textField} value={textValue} onChangeText={this.onInputChange}></TextInput>
            <Pressable onPress={this.onCopyPress} style={styles.copy}><Text></Text></Pressable>
        </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      flexDirection: 'row'
    },
    textField: {
      fontSize: 12,
      borderWidth: 1,
      borderRightWidth: 0
    },
    copy: {
        borderWidth: 1,
        paddingLeft: 4,
        paddingRight: 4,
        paddingTop:2,
        paddingBottom:2
    },
  });

I understand that I can use this component in a project by using something like the following in a parent component:
import { CopyInputBox } from './components/CopyInputBox';

class MyScreen {
  render() { 
    return ( 
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>Please enter</Text>
        <SelectedInputBox value="05-07-2024" />

        <Text>You entered: {textValue}</Text>        
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      flex: 1,
      backgroundColor: '#fff',
      alignItems: 'center',
      justifyContent: 'center',
    },
  });
  

I know the example does not fully work as there is no state management in place. The piece that I don't understand is how the textValue of the CopyInputBox makes it to the parent component. I'm trying to create a reusable library of components (CopyInputBox would be one of those components). While I understand there are libraries like Redux to handle state management. I do not want CopyInputBox to have a dependency on Redux. Instead, I would like for it to be state management library agnostic. In other words, I would be o.k. if MyScreen uses Redux, I just don't want CopyInputBox to force that dependency. Is that possible in React Native? If so, how?

Does this answer your question? How to pass data from child component to its parent in ReactJS?
